# Player Limit in a Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

There are some Minecraft servers that have a unique feature on the player limits: They have their limit set to 1, but players can still join. Here is a picture as an example of an existing Minecraft server that has this feature:

[image: Server Player Limit] <--Textured Packed

[image] <-- Default Look of Minecraft

I prefer not to show what server that is, but if it is needed, please let me know.

I was wondering: What is this unique feature?

Is it available for all servers that want it?

Will I be able to obtain it on my server, if yes, how?

I am in PC/Java (Windows) [Edited]

Comment: I would assume it's some server side mod. But I wonder why someone would want that. Why show a lower limit if it's not actually the real limit? Maybe they allow members with a certain status to join, even if the server is full? In that case they have massively overdone the assignment of these roles. But that still doesn't explain why the limit is so extremely low. Maybe the mod also automatically adjusts the limit to the server performance and they have such bad problems that it went to its minimum value? But that's all just speculation, this looks really weird to me.

Comment: Btw, did you change the background with a resource pack? Otherwise it would be a dirt texture.

Comment: And most importantly: You are talking about the PC/Java version of Minecraft, the one with the version number 1.12.2, right? Not Pocket, Windows 10, Console or whatever?

Comment: The Minecraft Backround is a TexturePack, and yes i am using PC/java using 1.10

If you wish to know the servers name to check it out let me know

Answer (score 2):

It's the result of using bungeecord which is a Spigot plugin. If you would want to achieve the same result, just put this in your bungee configuration file:

> listeners:
>
> - max_players: 1

If you don't use bungeecord and would want to do it anyway (and you use essentials), set the player slots to 1 and give everyone the permission

> essentials.joinfullserver

Answer (score 0):

this might be caused by a Server runing mutple smaller ones (minigames,maps,lobby's etc) 
also in normal terms (normal servers) this might mean the Max player amount is Very high (to high to show)

Answer (score 0):

I recognize this question is reaching one year old, however I noticed the previous answers were factually incorrect.

WWWubzy was correct in saying that it was caused by Bungee, however BungeeCord is NOT a spigot plugin. BungeeCord is a seperate server software much like Bukkit, Spigot and PaperMC. BungeeCord requires it's own Server to run on and functions as a way to connect multiple Servers together.

The BungeeCord configuration allows you to define (among other settings) two things:

```
max_players: 200
player_limit: -1
```

max_players is the number you saw in your screenshot. This limit is fake, meaning you can set it to 0 and players will still be able to join.

player_limit is the number of players allowed to join the server. Once the number of players on the server have reached this value new connections will be denied. This value can also be set to 0 or less to allow an unlimited amount of connections.